# Is it good to uninstall previous driver always before to install new version on Windows PC?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Is it good to uninstall previous driver always before to install new version on Windows PC?

I'm talking about any type of driver.

Answer (score 6):

No, it might even be bad.

Removing a driver instead of replacing it might leave you with a computer that's not functioning properly.

Admittedly modern OS'es ships with a decent amount of drivers that works "good enough" that this isn't as much of a problem that it was back in the Windows95/98 days.

Comment: This is a good answer. There is always the option of disabling drivers rather than uninstalling them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which drivers and which OS version are you upgrading from.  Display and audio drivers models changed substantially from XP to Vista.  Other than those two, I wouldn't worry.